# Parse a txt file into an array using bash and awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have the following CSV File called **test.csv**

```
First Line, 100
Second Line, 200
Third Line, 300
Fourth Line, 400
```

I want to split each line at the comma and store the first part into an array in a bash script using awk.
I have done the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a MY_ARRAY

MY_ARRAY=$(awk -F ',' '{print $1}' test.csv)
echo 'Start'
for ENTRY in ${MY_ARRAY}
do
echo ${ENTRY}
done
echo 'Stop'
```

And the output is as follows:

```
Start
First
Line
Second
Line
Third
Line
Fourth
Line
Stop
```

How can I get the array to hold the following?:

```
First Line
Second Line
Third Line
Fourth Line
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `awk` to populate a bash array? In every case it would be easier to use bash directly. Because of the spaces inside the fields you need more bash code than `array=( $(awk ...) )` anyway (note the `( )` around $( )`; you forgot them).

Comment: a few issues with the current code: **a)** assigning values to an array typically requires wrapping the right side of the assignment in parents, eg, `MY_ARRAY=( $(awk ... ) )`; **b)** since the `awk` output lines contain white space you need to redefine the default field separator as a `\n` for proper parsing into the array, eg, `IFS=$'\n' MY_ARRAY=( $(awk ... ) )` (all on one line so the `IFS` redefinition only applies to this command); **c)** to reference the individual elements of the array you need a wildcard match for the index (wrapped in `[]'s`), eg, `for ENTRY in "${MY_ARRAY[@]}"`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to assign a bash array to the first columns of csv file, you do not have to use `awk`. Please try instead:

```
readarray -t my_array < <(cut -d, -f1 test.csv)
for e in "${my_array[@]}"; do
    echo "$e"
done
```

Output:

```
First Line
Second Line
Third Line
Fourth Line
```

- The command `cut -t, -f1 file` splits each line on comma and prints the first field.
- The expression `<(command)` is a process substitution and can redirect the
  output of the command to another command (`readarray` in this case).
- The command `readarray -t my_array` reads lines from the standard input and assigns `my_array` to the lines.

Going back to your posted script, the variable `MY_ARRAY` is not assigned
as an array. It just holds a single string which contains whitespaces
and newlines. If it is referred as `for ENTRY in ${MY_ARRAY}`, the string
is split on the whitespaces and the newlines due to the `word splitting`
of bash.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat input 
First Line, 100
Second Line, 200
Third Line, 300
Fourth Line, 400

$ cat so.sh 
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=',' read -r -a array; do
    echo $array
done

$ cat input | ./so.sh 
First Line
Second Line
Third Line
Fourth Line
```

Comment: I need the script to open the file and read it, not have it cat-ed to the script

Comment: @HarryBoy But that is how to read from a file in bash.